# How to parse JSON in JavaScript to take value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am really stuck in parsing a JSON string and take it's values. I got the JSON string as

```
{"user":{"id":"1","firstname":"Freelogin","created":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","lastname":"Administrator","email":"fred@websecurify.com", "usergroup_id":"1","status":"1","ip_enable":"N","priv":"0","expire":""},"data":{ "1":{"5":{"last_update":"2010-12-13 16:16:16","status":"0"},"3":{"last_update":"2010-12-13 16:41:48","status":"1"}},"2":{"6":{"last_update":"2010-12-13 16:41:48","status":"1"}}},"server_array":[{"id":"1","name":"anes.yyy.net"},{ "id":"2","name":"neseema.xxx.net"}],"service_array":[{"id":"5","name":"POP3"}, {"id":"6","name":"Cpanel"},{"id":"3","name":"SMTP"}],"sort_by":"servername", "sort_order":"ASC","pagelinks":"","totrows":"2","offset":"0","limitvalue":"10", "rows_monitor":2,"current":"monitor","uri":false}
```

How to Parse this and take the Results for further
processing in JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).  It will use [native JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_JSON_in_Firefox) if available, and only use `eval` if necessary, after a sanity check.

Comment: Although a great solution (with a lot of overhead) in 2010, this should be avoided now.

Answer (score 2):

Use [JSON.parse](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-json.parse) (redirected from http://json.org), alternatively [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: This is the most correct answer. It is available in all current browsers (including IE 8+).

Answer (score 1):

Json is already some javascript. so parsing is just using `eval`

like:

```
 var foobar = eval(yourjson);
 alert(foobar.user);
```

Also jquery has some function for it [`jquery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

like:

```
   var foobar = $.parseJSON(yourjson);
```

Jquery is better because it would make some checks and perform better.

Comment: `eval` is insecure, and often [slower](http://www.vinylfox.com/json-decoding-speed-comparison/) than native parse.

Answer (score 1):

First, download [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Second, include it in your page.

Third, if your variable is this:

```
var jsonString = '{"user":{"id":"1","firstname":"Freelogin","created":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","lastname":"Administrator","email":"fred@websecurify.com", "usergroup_id":"1","status":"1","ip_enable":"N","priv":"0","expire":""},"data":{ "1":{"5":{"last_update":"2010-12-13 16:16:16","status":"0"},"3":{"last_update":"2010-12-13 16:41:48","status":"1"}},"2":{"6":{"last_update":"2010-12-13 16:41:48","status":"1"}}},"server_array":[{"id":"1","name":"anes.yyy.net"},{ "id":"2","name":"neseema.xxx.net"}],"service_array":[{"id":"5","name":"POP3"}, {"id":"6","name":"Cpanel"},{"id":"3","name":"SMTP"}],"sort_by":"servername", "sort_order":"ASC","pagelinks":"","totrows":"2","offset":"0","limitvalue":"10", "rows_monitor":2,"current":"monitor","uri":false}';
```

then,

```
var parsedJson = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);
```

will give you the desired parsed object that's ready for manipulation.

I tried out your JSON string on [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) and it says it's valid, so you should have no problems with it.

Comment: Your example (and possibly the question) is wrong.  `jsonString` is not JSON, or a string.  It's just a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

you probably got your json in som String variable

```
var json = '{"user":{"id":"1","firstname":"Freelogin","created":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","lastname":"Administrator","email":"fred@websecurify.com", "usergroup_id":"1","status":"1","ip_enable":"N","priv":"0","expire":""},"data":{ "1":{"5":{"last_update":"2010-12-13 16:16:16","status":"0"},"3":{"last_update":"2010-12-13 16:41:48","status":"1"}},"2":{"6":{"last_update":"2010-12-13 16:41:48","status":"1"}}},"server_array":[{"id":"1","name":"anes.yyy.net"},{ "id":"2","name":"neseema.xxx.net"}],"service_array":[{"id":"5","name":"POP3"}, {"id":"6","name":"Cpanel"},{"id":"3","name":"SMTP"}],"sort_by":"servername", "sort_order":"ASC","pagelinks":"","totrows":"2","offset":"0","limitvalue":"10", "rows_monitor":2,"current":"monitor","uri":false}';
```

now you can easily parse it via jQuery (you also can parse it via native javaScript eval, but there are some security issues, badly formated input string f.e., that is covered with jQuery and not in eval)

```
result = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
```

Now you can easily acces your json object

```
alert('Hello user, your name is ' + json.user.firstname);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery, in **ECMAScript5** JSON object will be supported natively and with it you can use **JSON.parse** method to parse a string into a JS object. IE9 will support ES5 and FF and Chrome already do.

For the moment you can use json2.js (you can look at the source [here](http://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)) as fallback for the browsers that don't support JSON natively.

Comment: IE 8 also supports `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`.