# How to loop through JSON and grab data?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Hi I have a local JSON file for football scores. How would I loop though it get a certain score or team name using JavaScript?

Below is the JSON:

```
{
   "w": 1,
   "t": "PRE",
   "gms":    [
            {
         "d": "Thu",
         "gsis": 55425,
         "h": "NE",
         "vnn": "Jaguars",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 12,
         "v": "JAC",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 47,
         "hnn": "Patriots",
         "t": "7:30",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081152
      },
            {
         "d": "Thu",
         "gsis": 55424,
         "h": "PHI",
         "vnn": "Ravens",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 6,
         "v": "BAL",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 13,
         "hnn": "Eagles",
         "t": "7:30",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081151
      },
            {
         "d": "Thu",
         "gsis": 55423,
         "h": "SD",
         "vnn": "Seahawks",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 24,
         "v": "SEA",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 17,
         "hnn": "Chargers",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081153
      },
            {
         "d": "Thu",
         "gsis": 55426,
         "h": "DAL",
         "vnn": "Broncos",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 23,
         "v": "DEN",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 24,
         "hnn": "Cowboys",
         "t": "8:30",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081154
      },
            {
         "d": "Thu",
         "gsis": 55427,
         "h": "OAK",
         "vnn": "Cardinals",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 24,
         "v": "ARI",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 18,
         "hnn": "Raiders",
         "t": "10:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081155
      },
            {
         "d": "Fri",
         "gsis": 55430,
         "h": "ATL",
         "vnn": "Dolphins",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 28,
         "v": "MIA",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 23,
         "hnn": "Falcons",
         "t": "7:30",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081252
      },
            {
         "d": "Fri",
         "gsis": 55429,
         "h": "DET",
         "vnn": "Bengals",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 3,
         "v": "CIN",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 34,
         "hnn": "Lions",
         "t": "7:30",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081251
      },
            {
         "d": "Fri",
         "gsis": 55431,
         "h": "WAS",
         "vnn": "Steelers",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 7,
         "v": "PIT",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 16,
         "hnn": "Redskins",
         "t": "7:30",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081253
      },
            {
         "d": "Fri",
         "gsis": 55428,
         "h": "KC",
         "vnn": "Buccaneers",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 25,
         "v": "TB",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 0,
         "hnn": "Chiefs",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081255
      },
            {
         "d": "Fri",
         "gsis": 55432,
         "h": "NO",
         "vnn": "49ers",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 3,
         "v": "SF",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 24,
         "hnn": "Saints",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081254
      },
            {
         "d": "Sat",
         "gsis": 55433,
         "h": "CLE",
         "vnn": "Packers",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 17,
         "v": "GB",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 27,
         "hnn": "Browns",
         "t": "7:30",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081351
      },
            {
         "d": "Sat",
         "gsis": 55437,
         "h": "CAR",
         "vnn": "Giants",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 10,
         "v": "NYG",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 20,
         "hnn": "Panthers",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081355
      },
            {
         "d": "Sat",
         "gsis": 55434,
         "h": "CHI",
         "vnn": "Bills",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 3,
         "v": "BUF",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 10,
         "hnn": "Bears",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081352
      },
            {
         "d": "Sat",
         "gsis": 55435,
         "h": "STL",
         "vnn": "Colts",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 10,
         "v": "IND",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 33,
         "hnn": "Rams",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081353
      },
            {
         "d": "Sat",
         "gsis": 55436,
         "h": "TEN",
         "vnn": "Vikings",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 3,
         "v": "MIN",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 14,
         "hnn": "Titans",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081354
      },
            {
         "d": "Mon",
         "gsis": 55438,
         "h": "HOU",
         "vnn": "Jets",
         "q": "P",
         "vs": 0,
         "v": "NYJ",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 0,
         "hnn": "Texans",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081551
      }
   ],
   "y": 2011,
   "gd": "0"
}
```

Sorry guys I am still learning and want to be able to master this.

So would I do

eval(JSONfile) ?? I am not sure what to do here to parse and read this?

Comment: That's not JSON, that is a JavaScript object literal. Show us the code you've tried so far, and explain exactly how and why it isn't working for you.

Comment: @Matt: I can only assume OP is showing server-side markup that needs to be parsed. At least I assume that's what is meant by *"I have a local JSON file"*.

Comment: @Matt: Maybe it's obvious, but I don't see it - why isn't this JSON?

Comment: @Matt Ball. That is JSON. What do you expect JSON to look like? JSON is a JavaScript object literal. eval(JSONString); will always output a JavaScript object. http://json.org/

Comment: It's the trouble of having JSON modeled after JavaScript structures. Just add `var json = `, and suddenly you're talking about an object literal.

Comment: @Robin: JSON is *not* a JavaScript object literal. It's a text format that can be *converted into* an object literal, or into the proper structure for a number of different languages.

Comment: @Bob @keks @Robin the difference lies in how a JS interpreter will parse the two. JSON is a notation for storing object literal data **in a string.** A JS interpreter will parse JSON into a **string** - N.B. I am **not** talking about `eval`ing JSON. A JS interpreter will parse an object literal into an **object.**

Comment: This is a variable which references a JSON string: `var json = '{"foo": "bar"}';`

Comment: This is a variable which references an object: `var obj = {"foo": "bar"};`.

Comment: @patrick dw. Okay so it's a string format, with exactly the same notation as a JavaScript object literal. So how can Matt Ball possibly say that the above *string* isn't JSON?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript to take value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448192/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript-to-take-value)

Comment: @Matt That's kind of an odd distinction. What would this be? eval("x = 7"); That's a string, but it's also a JavaScript assignment to a variable named x. I'm not sure there's much distinction between being a string and actual code in JavaScript.

Comment: Hey (it's me again). It looks like what you want to do is pull that script in with something like jQuery's getScript: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/. That link will show you the function and how to use it.

Comment: @Bob: Sure there is. Everything between `"` or `'` is a string. Don't tell me `"foo@bar"` is JavaScript code. Of course a string can have content which can be interpreted by `eval` as JS code. But that does not make a JSON string a JavaScript object literal or vice versa.

Comment: @Jackson: You really don't want to try to treat JSON data like all other JavaScript code unless you absolutely control the source of it. I'm certain this code is coming from an external source, and as such, should be treated with proper security measures, like having it parsed as valid JSON.

Comment: @Bob: But why can't you just do `"x = 7"; alert( x );`? Because there's a distinction. The string in your example was parsed and evaluated as JavaScript code. Until you do that, there's a very real distinction.

Comment: @Bob `eval("x = 7")` is neither JSON nor a JavaScript object literal. It's a **function call.** See [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) §11.2.3.

Comment: @Felix And if JSON is in a file, like the OP's example, then there is no " or '. But it's still JSON. But at that point it's impossible to know if it's just an object literal or JSON because they really are the same thing at the end of the day. The distinction is only important within JavaScript code when you're assigning to a variable. If it's within quotes it's JSON, otherwise an object literal. If it's being eval'ed they're the same thing as far as JavaScript is concerned.

Comment: @Bob `eval("x = 7")` is most certainly not the same thing as `eval(x = 7)`!

Comment: @Bob: I never said that the above is not JSON. I only wanted to pointed out that there *is* a difference between strings and code in JS. Of course, without context, it is not easy to decide what something actually represents. If I didn't know that we are talking about JavaScript, `eval("x = 7");` could be Python as well. The point is that a lot people refer to JavaScript object literals as *JSON objects* and that is plain wrong.

Comment: @Bob: *"...at that point it's impossible to know if it's just an object literal or JSON because they really are the same thing at the end of the day."* Same thing? So `'{"func":function(){}}'` is JSON? If you've spliced your JSON file into a script that is being loaded with the page, then it will naturally be evaluated immediately as JavaScript objects. If you're fetching the file via an AJAX call, it will arrive as text that needs to be parsed into JavaScript objects.

Comment: Ok folks....can you take this debate over to a chat room please. Thanks.

Comment: @Robin: Oops, I missed that comment. Didn't mean to ignore. If you look at the second comment, you'll see that I told him I thought it was server-side JSON markup. His comment doesn't make some of the other comments any more valid.

Answer (score 1):

To parse it, you could use `.eval()` as you noted in your question.

Better is to use a JSON parser. Modern browsers have it built in:

```
var js_obj = JSON.parse( my_json );
```

For browsers that don't support `JSON.parse`, you can include the [json2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) that will add `.parse` and `.stringify`.

Then just enumerate with a `for-in` statement (or a `for` statement for Arrays) like you normally would.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, then `$.each` might be cleaner solution, but it's mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: @allencoded: If you're *already* using jQuery, then use `var js_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(my_json)`. Even then, I'd be inclined to include a proper JSON parser that jQuery can use if the native one isn't present. But it would be overkill to load jQuery just for that purpose.

Comment: ...and I'd agree with @Xion that `$.each()` does make it a bit cleaner.

Comment: Just note that `$.each` requires providing nested function and this has slightly different semantics than `for-in` loop (e.g. the referent of `this` inside that function is set by jQuery to the current element and is most likely not equal to the referent of `this` in the outer function).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry didn't tell you how to read in the JSON string.

If you are writing the string straight into the JavaScipt, E.g. with PHP, you can just set it straight as a variable:

```
var scores = <?php echo $scoresJSON ?>
```

If it's stored in JavaScript as a string, then you can use JSON.parse if it's supported, otherwise eval:

```
var scores = {};
if(typeof(JSON) === 'object') { scores = JSON.parse(jsonString); }
else { scores = eval(jsonString); }
```

Or you can use jQuery's methods.

References:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON#Parsing_JSON.c2.a0strings

As for then using the data:

```
/**
 * Return array of all scores for a team acronym
 * E.g. for MIN it would return: [3]
 * If the same team had multiple games it would return scores for all games.
 * E.g.: [3, 6, 0, 23]
 */
function getScoresForTeam(teamAcronym, scoresObject) {
    // Create scores array, to populate later
    var scores = [];

    // Look through each game in JSON
    for(i = 0; i < jsonString.gms.length; i++) {
        var thisGame = jsonString.gms[i]
        // Check if they were team 'v'
        if(thisGame.v === teamAcronym) {
            scores.push(thisGame.vs);
        } else if(thisGame.h === teamAcronym) {
            scores.push(thisGame.hs);
        }
    }

    // Return scores array
    return scores;
}
```

I tested this in browser (Chrome):

```
> getScoresForTeam('MIN',scores);
> [3]
```

Comment: But you need to parse the JSON first.