# How to traverse a javascript array/object

Tags: javascript

I am having a hard time trying to get my data from this array. Can someone please tell me how to do this?

I need to get the `latLng` and `AdminArea4` from within the `locations` for an autocomplete.

Can someone please explain the difference between the `{}` and `[]`. From what I know, one is an array and the other an object but I am not sure if this is right. Is the process different from traversing an array than an object?

```
{
   "results": [
      {
         "locations": [
            {
               "latLng": {
                  "lng": 24.873108,
                  "lat": 59.389755
               },
               "adminArea4": "Harju maakond",
               "adminArea5Type": "City",
               "adminArea4Type": "County",
               "adminArea5": "Rae vald",
               "street": "",
               "adminArea1": "EE",
               "adminArea3": "",
               "type": "s",
               "displayLatLng": {
                  "lng": 24.873108,
                  "lat": 59.389755
               },
               "linkId": 0,
               "postalCode": "",
               "sideOfStreet": "N",
               "dragPoint": false,
               "adminArea1Type": "Country",
               "geocodeQuality": "CITY",
               "geocodeQualityCode": "A5XXX",
               "adminArea3Type": "State"
            },
            {
               "latLng": {
                  "lng": 24.860184,
                  "lat": 59.38493
               },
               "adminArea4": "Harju maakond",
               "adminArea5Type": "City",
               "adminArea4Type": "County",
               "adminArea5": "Rae",
               "street": "",
               "adminArea1": "EE",
               "adminArea3": "",
               "type": "s",
               "displayLatLng": {
                  "lng": 24.860184,
                  "lat": 59.38493
               },
               "linkId": 0,
               "postalCode": "",
               "sideOfStreet": "N",
               "dragPoint": false,
               "adminArea1Type": "Country",
               "geocodeQuality": "CITY",
               "geocodeQualityCode": "A5XXX",
               "adminArea3Type": "State"
            },
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Yet another "How to parse JSON object with JavaScript" ... sigh.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript to take value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448192/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript-to-take-value)

Comment: Is this an array or an object? I really want to know more about how to parse this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First some explanation about arrays and objects since you've asked and it's quite relevant to how to use the data structure you have:

`{}` defines an object.  `[]` defines an array.

An object is a unordered list of property/value pairs with no property name repeated.

An array is an ordered list of individual items with a `.length` property that tells you how many items are in the array.

---

An object would be defined like this:

```
var obj = {
   prop1: value1,
   prop2: value2
};
```

And, you can reference values like this:

```
console.log(obj.prop1);    // value1
```

An array is defined like this:

```
var myArray = ["one", "two", "three"];
```

And, you can access elements by zero-based index like this:

```
console.log(myArray[0]);   // "one"
```

Or, you can iterate all the items in an array like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

---

Assuming your overall data structure is in a variable named `data`, you can iterate the results and nested locations arrays like this:

```
var results = data.results;
var locations;
for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
    locations = results[j].locations;
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
       console.log(locations[i].latLng);
       console.log(locations[i].adminArea4);
    }
```

To explain:

1. `data.results` is an array that you need to iterate.
2. In each element of that array is an object with a locations property in it.
3. The locations property is another array that you need to iterate.
4. In each element of the locations array is an object with a `latLng` property and a `adminArea4` property on it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried your loop and what I am getting is `TypeError: results[i] is undefined`

Comment: @NaN - yes, that was a typo in my answer.  `results[i]` should have been `results[j]`.  Answer corrected now.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. It seems to be giving me more now. If I wanted to access the actual value of the lat, could I just do `locations[i].latLng.lat`? Also, can you tell me if I would still need a for loop if I used the `parseJSON` function?

Comment: @NaN - yes you would just use `locations[i].latLng.lat`.  Your data is already parsed from JSON into Javascript so `parseJSON()` is not appropriate here. You need the loops if you want to get all values returned in the data.  It takes some sort of loop to iterate through the arrays in the data that can hold more than one value.

Comment: OK, thank you for the explanation here, jsfriend. Can you please tell me why objects and arrays are mixed? Why not just use one or the other?

Comment: @NaN - this data structure contains lists of data and each piece of data has multiple named properties. To express this, it is very common to have an array of objects.  Here you have something more complicated than normal because you have an array of results where each result is itself an object containing an array of objects.  Fortunately, they aren't usually this complicated to navigate.  If you just wanted a list of random numbers, you'd just use a single array to hold the numbers.  If you just want a single object with a bunch of different named properties, you'd just use an object.

Comment: Thank you for the outstanding explanation, jfriend00. It actually makes sense. So to have an array of objects is logical. I am also glad to hear that this example is not all that common. I have always struggled with arrays, so this is welcome news. Thanks again for all your help and for the great explanations!

Answer (score 1):

It's json structure.. You can access elements as I mentioned below.. Assign json to variable and then access object properties.

```
var obj = {
   "results": [
      {
         "locations": [
            {
               "latLng": {
                  "lng": 24.873108,
                  "lat": 59.389755
               },
               "adminArea4": "Harju maakond",
               "adminArea5Type": "City",
               "adminArea4Type": "County",
               "adminArea5": "Rae vald",
               "street": "",
               "adminArea1": "EE",
               "adminArea3": "",
               "type": "s",
               "displayLatLng": {
                  "lng": 24.873108,
                  "lat": 59.389755
               },
               "linkId": 0,
               "postalCode": "",
               "sideOfStreet": "N",
               "dragPoint": false,
               "adminArea1Type": "Country",
               "geocodeQuality": "CITY",
               "geocodeQualityCode": "A5XXX",
               "adminArea3Type": "State"
            },
            {
               "latLng": {
                  "lng": 24.860184,
                  "lat": 59.38493
               },
               "adminArea4": "Harju maakond",
               "adminArea5Type": "City",
               "adminArea4Type": "County",
               "adminArea5": "Rae",
               "street": "",
               "adminArea1": "EE",
               "adminArea3": "",
               "type": "s",
               "displayLatLng": {
                  "lng": 24.860184,
                  "lat": 59.38493
               },
               "linkId": 0,
               "postalCode": "",
               "sideOfStreet": "N",
               "dragPoint": false,
               "adminArea1Type": "Country",
               "geocodeQuality": "CITY",
               "geocodeQualityCode": "A5XXX",
               "adminArea3Type": "State"
            },
         ]
      }
   ]
};
```

> Travsering Values

```
obj.results[0].locations[0].latLng.lng
obj.results[0].locations[0].latLng.lat
```

You can also traverse by using for loop.

Comment: Thank you razahassank. My data is coming back from a server, so can I assign what is returned from the server to a variable?

Comment: it's better to parse it by using jquery.. e.g. var obj = $.parseJSON(serverResponse);

Comment: There's more than one location in the locations array and potentially more than one result in the `results` array.  This only obtains one hardwired location - skipping any others that are present.

Comment: @razahassank, thank you for the function. What I get from that is `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just ran the JSON through the validator and it says `Valid JSON`