# Javascript: Help Parsing weird JSON payload

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to parse the following JSON payload:

```
{
   "results":[
      [
         298.648132,
         280.68692,
         356.54184,
         388.085541,
         183.491806,
         -484.676086,
         -468.069916,
         -446.741699
      ],
      [
         299.641846,
         285.005798,
         358.563812,
         389.283997,
         212.144806,
         -485.533844,
         -469.071533,
         -447.885406
      ],
      [
         302.24469,
         291.76059,
         362.658936,
         392.376129,
         217.732513,
         -484.816711,
         -468.566711,
         -447.615082
      ],
      [
         303.058899,
         297.929199,
         365.46994,
         393.894928,
         213.591797,
         -486.055756,
         -469.872986,
         -449.343323
      ],
      [
         304.604095,
         304.826233,
         369.112122,
         396.274597,
         206.882492,
         -486.385498,
         -470.249512,
         -450.089935
      ],
      [
         305.541901,
         306.31842,
         370.016907,
         396.985413,
         200.299408,
         -486.345032,
         -470.176208,
         -450.01059
      ],
      [
         305.137024,
         306.015381,
         369.381042,
         396.26059,
         196.422821,
         -487.490143,
         -471.321533,
         -451.191711
      ],
      [
         306.182373,
         307.574707,
         370.42627,
         397.127747,
         206.874603,
         -487.188477,
         -471.038483,
         -450.869781
      ],
      [
         307.108887,
         309.183777,
         371.413666,
         397.890198,
         234.509079,
         -486.957367,
         -470.937103,
         -450.646393
      ],
      [
         308.208923,
         310.277588,
         372.322968,
         398.777618,
         244.5168,
         -486.2995,
         -470.352631,
         -449.89325
      ],
      [
         308.676208,
         310.526123,
         372.360626,
         398.743317,
         250.976288,
         -486.666687,
         -470.868408,
         -450.324463
      ],
      [
         308.910583,
         310.629242,
         372.255676,
         398.59491,
         252.538498,
         -487.001068,
         -471.305817,
         -450.616699
      ]
   ],
   "columns":[
      "5bb6a5d20ff4c313aab7241c.value.value",
      "5bb6a5d30ff4c313aab72421.value.value",
      "5bb6a5d30ff4c313aab72425.value.value",
      "5bb6a5d30ff4c313aab72426.value.value",
      "5bb6a5d30ff4c313091fe079.value.value",
      "5bb6a5d30ff4c313091fe07b.value.value",
      "5bb6a5d30ff4c313091fe07c.value.value",
      "5bb6a5d40ff4c313091fe07f.value.value"
   ]
}
```

I am only interested in the "results" section. I will end up plotting these values.
I am proficient in C++, but new to JavaScript.
I've found plenty of examples with typical JSON strings, but I haven't found anything that works for this yet.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The obvious thing to try is JSON.parse.  How did that not work for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in JavaScript to take value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448192/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript-to-take-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function:

```
const payload = // your json payload
const json = JSON.parse(payload);
const results = json.results;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can copy-paste your json to your JS code directly then try

```
const payload = {"results": [ ... } // your json
const results = payload.results;
```

```js
const payload ={"results":[[298.648132,280.68692,356.54184,388.085541,183.491806,-484.676086,-468.069916,-446.741699],
[299.641846,285.005798,358.563812,389.283997,212.144806,-485.533844,-469.071533,-447.885406],
[302.24469,291.76059,362.658936,392.376129,217.732513,-484.816711,-468.566711,-447.615082],
[303.058899,297.929199,365.46994,393.894928,213.591797,-486.055756,-469.872986,-449.343323],
[304.604095,304.826233,369.112122,396.274597,206.882492,-486.385498,-470.249512,-450.089935],
[305.541901,306.31842,370.016907,396.985413,200.299408,-486.345032,-470.176208,-450.01059],
[305.137024,306.015381,369.381042,396.26059,196.422821,-487.490143,-471.321533,-451.191711],
[306.182373,307.574707,370.42627,397.127747,206.874603,-487.188477,-471.038483,-450.869781],
[307.108887,309.183777,371.413666,397.890198,234.509079,-486.957367,-470.937103,-450.646393],
[308.208923,310.277588,372.322968,398.777618,244.5168,-486.2995,-470.352631,-449.89325],
[308.676208,310.526123,372.360626,398.743317,250.976288,-486.666687,-470.868408,-450.324463],
[308.910583,310.629242,372.255676,398.59491,252.538498,-487.001068,-471.305817,-450.616699]],
"columns":["5bb6a5d20ff4c313aab7241c.value.value","5bb6a5d30ff4c313aab72421.value.value",
"5bb6a5d30ff4c313aab72425.value.value","5bb6a5d30ff4c313aab72426.value.value",
"5bb6a5d30ff4c313091fe079.value.value","5bb6a5d30ff4c313091fe07b.value.value",
"5bb6a5d30ff4c313091fe07c.value.value","5bb6a5d40ff4c313091fe07f.value.value"]}

const results = payload.results;
console.log(results);
```